# De-identifying survival or flexsurvreg objects in R

Tags: r, privacy, survival

Please consider the following:

I need to provide some R code syntax to analyse data with the `flexsurv` package. I am not allowed to receive/analyse directly or on-site. I am however allowed to receive the analysis results.

---

**Problem**

When we run the `flexsurvreg()` function on some data (here `ovarian` from the `flexsurv` package), the created object (here `fitw`) contains enough information to "re-create" or "back-engineer" the actual data. But then I would technically have access to the data I am not allowed to have.

```r
# Load package
library("flexsurv")
#> Loading required package: survival

# Run flexsurvreg with data = ovarian
fitw <- flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(futime, fustat) ~ factor(rx) + age,
                    data = ovarian, dist="weibull")

# Look at first observation in ovarian
ovarian[1, ]
#>   futime fustat     age resid.ds rx ecog.ps
#> 1     59      1 72.3315        2  1       1

# With the following from the survival object, the data could be re-created
fitw$data$Y[1, ]
#>   time status  start   stop  time1  time2 
#>     59      1      0     59     59    Inf
fitw$data$m[1, ]
#>   Surv(futime, fustat) factor(rx)     age (weights)
#> 1                   59          1 72.3315         1
```

---

**Potential solution**

We could write the code so that it also sets all those data that might be used for this back-engineering to `NA` as follows:

```r
# Setting all survival object observation to NA
fitw$data$Y <- NA
fitw$data$m <- NA
fitw$data$mml$scale <- NA
fitw$data$mml$rate <- NA
fitw$data$mml$mu <- NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

**Question**

If I proceed as the above and set all these parameters to `NA`, could I then receive the `fitw` object (e.g. as an `.RDS` file) without ever being able to "back-engineer" the original data? Or is there any other way to share `fitw` without the attached data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting, e.g. `fitw$data <- NULL` will remove all the individual-level data from the fitted model object.   Some of the output functions may not work with objects stripped of data however.   In the current development version on [github](https://github.com/chjackson/flexsurv-dev/), printing the model object should work.  Also summary and predict methods should work, as long as covariate values are supplied in `newdata` - omitting them won't work, since the default is to take the covariate values from the observed data.